# Plot marker on map from autocomplete item clicked

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database, autocompletetextview

I am able to display all items from Autocomplete suggestion but when i click an item i want the longitude and latitude coordinates associated with the item to be plotted on the map. I currently dont know how to achieve. `please help here.

**I have pasted my method below**

```
private void searchAutocomplete(){
    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    //Create a new ArrayAdapter with your context and the simple layout for the dropdown menu provided by Android
    final ArrayAdapter<String> autoComplete = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    //Child the root before all the push() keys are found and add a ValueEventListener()
    database.child("wr").child("clubs").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Basically, this says "For each DataSnapshot *Data* in dataSnapshot, do what's inside the method.
            for (DataSnapshot suggestionSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                //Get the suggestion by childing the key of the string you want to get.
                String suggestion = suggestionSnapshot.child("name1").getValue(String.class);
                //Add the retrieved string to the list
                autoComplete.add(suggestion);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    AutoCompleteTextView ACTV= (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autocompleteView);
    ACTV.setAdapter(autoComplete);
    ACTV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update `final ArrayAdapter<String> autoComplete` to instead be something like `final ArrayAdapter<Place> autoComplete` and then implement something like:

public class Place {

```
private float latitude;
private float longitude;
private String name;

// implement your constructor
// implement your accessors
```

}

And then from your `onClick` you would received the `Place`, and you can just do something like `place.getLatitude()` and `place.getLongitude`.

That's how I would implement this.

Comment: I am getting data from Firebase not Google Place API

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to listen for click events and add a `Marker` when an item is clicked.

Example:

```
tv.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, pos, id) -> {
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(mDataList.get(pos).getLocation()));
});
```

You'll need to make sure your google map has been loaded of course.

Comment: They're using Firebase not the PlaceAutocomplete widget.

Comment: Whether they are using Firebase is irrelevant to the question, and I made no mention of Place Autocomplete.

Comment: can you explain a bit i mean where does the mDataList come in or how do initialize it?